# Javamail Getting one extra file On downloading attachments

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I'm getting one extra file of type `File` on downloading attachments. I'm using `MimeBodyPart.saveFile()` here is my download attachment code

```
for (MimeBodyPart mbp : msgToDownload.getAttachmentList()) {
     updateProgress(msgToDownload.getAttachmentList().indexOf(mbp),
     msgToDownload.getAttachmentList().size());
     mbp.saveFile(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION + mbp.getFileName());
 }
```

here `msgToDownload` is a Class that take `Message msg` as parameter with some other parameters. And `getAttachmentList()` is a list of type **MimeBodyPart** defined as `List<MimeBodyPart>`
This is how I'm adding attachments to list

```
    sb.setLength(0);
        msgToRender.clearAttachments();
        Message msg = msgToRender.getMsgRef();
        try {
//            String messageType = msg.getContentType();

            sb.append(getText(msg));

            if (hasAttachments(msg)) {
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                for (int i = mp.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);

                    MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) bp;
                    msgToRender.addAttachment(mbp);
                }
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
```

Extra file contain attributes of text part of the Mail. Content of extra file

> -001a114fd0aa0b377d0546bb84a0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 please find the attachments... --001a114fd0aa0b377d0546bb84a0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 please find the attachments... --001a114fd0aa0b377d0546bb84a0--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should learn about the [isMimeType](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#isMimeType-java.lang.String-) method.

The problem is most likely that you're not handling multipart/alternative messages.  See the [sample code in the JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).

Comment: while downloading attachments now my program also download a file that contain all information like `content-type` and text message in that file. But I do not want it to download that info.

Comment: Even if a message has not attachment it download one with text attributes.

Comment: And in the code above I believe `messageType.contains("multipart")` means all type of multipart either `multipart/ alternative` or other type of multipart. Is not that true.

Comment: 1. Show me how you're downloading something that's not giving you what you want.  2. Show me how it downloads an attachment for a message with no attachments.  3. Yes, contains("multipart") will match all kinds of multipart (which is the bug).  It will also match things that are not multipart.

Comment: this is how i'm adding attachments
`if (hasAttachments(msg)) {
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                for (int i = mp.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);

                    MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) bp;
                    msgToRender.addAttachment(mbp);
                }
            }`

Comment: And how i'm downloading attachments
`for (MimeBodyPart mbp : msgToRender.getAttachmentList()) {
                    mbp.saveFile(DOWNLOAD_LOCATION + mbp.getFileName());
                }`

Comment: In above two comments `msgToRender` is a Class that take `Message msg` as parameter with some other parameters. And `getAttachmentList()` is a list of type `MimeBodyPart` defined as `List<MimeBodyPart>`

Comment: One extra file of type `File` has text when I open it in notepad here is its text
`--001a114fd0aa0b377d0546bb84a0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

please find the attachments...

--001a114fd0aa0b377d0546bb84a0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">please find the attachments...</div>

--001a114fd0aa0b377d0546bb84a0--`

Comment: For more detail check out stuff on github [SaveAttachmentsService](https://github.com/Inzimam-Tariq/Mail_Client/blob/master/src/org/itsoftsolutions/controller/Services/SaveAttachmentsService.java),
[MessageRendererService](https://github.com/Inzimam-Tariq/Mail_Client/blob/master/src/org/itsoftsolutions/controller/Services/MessageRendererService.java), [Overall project Link](https://github.com/Inzimam-Tariq/Mail_Client)

Comment: Please update your original post with this information in a format that's readable.

Comment: Did you read about multipart/alternative and the sample code in the JavaMail FAQ?  Everything you have above suggests that you did not, or that you didn't understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133864/discussion-between-inzimam-tariq-it-and-bill-shannon).